# How to operate over subset of row on pandas data frame?

Tags: pandas

```py
def getDF(threshold):
    df = pd.read_pickle(filename)

    df['threshold'] = float(threshold)
    df.set_index('date')

    df['anomaly'] = [any values of the row] > df['threshold']
```

I have the above function that needs to set the `anomaly` column if any of the floats, `columns 0 - 9`, are greater than the threshold. I know how to do this on one column but what about multiple?

I could probably do this with brute force the long way, but I'm sure there is a pandas way of doing it much faster.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first calculate the *row-wise maximum*, and then check if this maximum is greater than the threshold:

```
df['anomaly'] = df[['column1', 'column2', 'column3']].max(axis=1) > df['threshold']
```

If the threshold is however a *single* value, then you can simply use the value itself:

```
df['anomaly'] = df[['column1', 'column2', 'column3']].max(axis=1) > threshold
```

or for the first ten columns:

```
df['anomaly'] = df.iloc[:,:10].max(axis=1) > threshold
```

Comment: columns 0 - 9 do not have names, If it helps there are 12 cols total and I dont want to check against the columns named 'date' and 'threshold' and I guess 'anomaly' once its been assigned. Is there some say to say all the columns except [these]?

Comment: @SwimMaster: you can use `.iloc[:,:10]` for the first ten columns.